# What are the colors correspond on image which is generated by Laplace filter in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv

In Sobel operator the colors are to indicate the edge direction: yellow for 0 degrees, green for 45 degrees, blue for 90 degrees and red for 135 degrees. However I am not sure what each color corresponds on Laplace filtered image.

I would like to extract approximately red pixels from Laplace filtered image which gives me some useful information. Although, I am yet to understand when it presents red pixels and when not.

[image: Original Image][image: After Laplace filtering]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colors in the output of Sobel operator are not for what you mentioned. If you apply any filter, either Sobel or Laplacian or any other, to a 3 channel image, OpenCV just applies the filter to each channel independently, and then combines the result. The colors in the output are just the combined effect of edges detected in each channel.

Color edge detection is not done by simple applying the edge detection filter to each channel of the image. There are specialized algorithms for this e.g DiZenzo Gradients.

Comment: I found that information which is about the output of Sobel operator on Wikipedia. Here the links for it: 
[Canny-edge-detector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector), 
[sobel-with-angle-colour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Valve_sobel_with_angle_colour_%284%29.PNG), 
[another-related-information](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/alumni/bGreen/www.pages.drexel.edu/_weg22/can_tut.html).
I misunderstood the things or more explanation may needed in this answer.